# Replace Comma surrounded by String w/Semi-colon in Netbeans

Tags: regex, netbeans

I need to replace all instances of letter-comma-letter with letter-semicolon-letter (or number). The letter can be standalone or part of a larger word. Case-insensitive.

`a,b` -> `a;b`

`alpha,beta` -> `alpha;beta`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
(.+),(.+)
```

with this

```
\1;\2
```

If the words are not on a line on their own but inside sentences then use either of these

```
(\w),(\w)
([^,]),([^,])
```

The replacement string is the same

Comment: This does not work. Your regex highlights the entire row.

Comment: of course it must match the whole line, otherwise without context how can one know what to find? If the string is surrounded by some text then you must also provide that too